# How to start and stop ping federation using a unix script

Tags: ping, federation

I need a script to start and stop the pingfederate server using a unix script. I am looking for a best practise to start and stop pingfederate using the script

Comment: which OS and distribution exactly?

Comment: It is redhat enterprise version 6.6, version of pingfederate is 7.1.0 R3

Answer (score 1):

http://documentation.pingidentity.com/display/PF72/Running+PingFederate+as+a+Service has:

```
#! /bin/sh

start() {
  echo "starting PingFederate.."
  su - <pf_user> \
  -c '<pf_install>/pingfederate/sbin/pingfederate-run.sh \
  > /dev/null 2> /dev/null'
}

stop() {
  echo "stopping PingFederate.."
  su - <pf_user> \
  -c '<pf_install>/pingfederate/sbin/\
     pingfederate-shutdown.sh'
}

restart(){
  stop
  # padding time to stop before restart
  sleep 60
  # To protect against any services that are not stopped,
  # uncomment the following command.
  # (Warning: this kills all Java instances running as
  # <pf_user>.)
  #   su - <pf_user> -c 'killall java'
  start
}

case "$1" in
  start)
     start
     ;;
  stop)
     stop
     ;;
  restart)
     restart
     ;;
  *)
  echo "Usage: <pf_user> {start|stop|restart}"
  exit 1
esac
exit 0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. I also have my Run time Engine running. therefore i will have to follow a sequence order of starting the server instances. so i have to first start the admin server and then start the run time engine next. If by chance we start run time engine without the admin up and running, the script should report an error. I am not able to execute this use case. How do we find whether the Admin server is running or not.

Comment: no, the order of starting nodes (engine, admin) in the cluster does not matter

Comment: Fine. Thanks for your help. Can u help me how to execute this script. Should i give script_name.sh start

Comment: just follow the steps in the link http://documentation.pingidentity.com/display/PF72/Running+PingFederate+as+a+Service and name it "pingfederate"; no extension, just like the other init.d scripts